# Need a regular expression to match a pattern

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to match below pattern

```
Word1 OR Word2 OR Word3 OR......
```

basically this is a string which contains words split by OR

Comment: I am pretty new to regular expressions.Dont know much about them :(

Comment: Go to www.regular-expression.info and read the tutorial.

Comment: Which lang are you running? What's your expected output?

Comment: Do you want to extract the individual words or just match the whole thing?

Comment: Want to match the whole thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will match based on what you've given:

```
^\w+(?: OR \w+)*$
```

> `^` assert position at start of the string
>   `\w+` match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
>   `Quantifier: +` Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
>   `(?: OR \w+)*` Non-capturing group
>   `Quantifier: *` Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
>   `_OR_` matches the characters `_OR_` literally (case sensitive)
>   `\w+` match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
>   `Quantifier: +` Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
>   `$` assert position at end of the string

NOTE: I used `_OR_` to show the spaces around `OR` in the quotation as the whitespace was ignored.

Link to [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kX1wO9/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
(\w+)(?=(?:\s+OR)|(?:\s*$))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xY7zQ4/2)

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this and access the second group using \2:

```
((\w+)\sOR)*
```

Try playing with the link below, read the explanation and you'll understand how it works:
https://regex101.com/r/vY6mA7/1

Comment: This doesn't match all the words in the string?

Comment: This also won't match `Word1` on its own.

Comment: it does on the second group; depends on what is the goal in the end I guess